# face_recognition knn algorithm: Is it possible add more faces in the generated .clf file without have to retrain everything again?

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-vision, face-recognition, knn

I'm using the KNN method from [face_recognition](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/blob/master/examples/face_recognition_knn.py) library to train some faces, this method generate a .clf file with a trained model used for recognition. Can I add more faces in this file without have to train everything again?

[Parallel thread in GitHub](https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/492)

Answer (score 0):

It is convenient to use the `transfer learning` method, building your classification on top of a pre-trained model.

In this case, you'll use pre-train weights from a consistent model, and train your dataset on top of that, changing the network only at classification layers.

For facial (and emotion) recognition, `VGG-16` models are indicated, and you'll have better accuracy.

For more information, please refer to this link:

https://github.com/anujshah1003/Transfer-Learning-Face-Recognition-using-VGG-16

Comment: I'll read a little more about your method. I was just researching this, if there was a more "professional" way of doing what I'm wanting, add more data to a pre-trained model. I already did it with OpenCV and Haar Cascade, but I have not seen many people using the same function. From what I've read, this library I'm using does what you say, uses a pre-model of millions of faces for face detection and another for recognition (.clf), I got good results by adding a significative number of faces. The only problem I had was that I had to retrain the whole model if I wanted to add more faces to it.

Comment: with transfer learning you are not retraining the whole model, because all weights up to classification layers remain the same. the only novelty learned by the algorithm happens at classification level, where your new data is applied. it would take ages to retrain it all. if you add new data, it takes much less time. but the model must learn from new faces, of course.

Comment: As far as I can see the two libraries work the same way, in the face_recognition KNN method the files are trained and saved, in .clf format, separately from the detection file. To train the model to detect a face with good precision I'm using about 50 images, it takes about 10 minutes.

Comment: Oh, well. to train a model from scratch, I use 40.000 images, or 10.000 per class...thats the base used for `Imagenet` project. it takes an entire day with CPU mode, and for transfer learning I use at least 200 for each class.